# Is it safe for astronaut to do this "dangerous" movement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

So, if the astronaut is working outside the space station in thew space, could he not tie himself onto the space station and if he is going further away of the space station, i think he could just inginite a firework and use the reaction force to make himeself back to the station, is it true? i think since the space have no air resistance, theotically he could travel a long distance by using small amount of energy?

Comment: For firework you need oxygen, which is not present in space, but the theory of conservation of energy may work, but I expect it to be a bit dangerous

Comment: @Bernhard fireworks don't need oxygen, like most other types of rockets and explosives they include oxidizing agents themselves. They would probably still not work in space, because of the lacking air _pressure_. but in a pure inert argon atmosphere there is no problem.

Comment: leftaroundabout: Rockets don't need an atmosphere for propulsion. In fact, they are more efficient in vacuum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently in orbit, it's informally called the Buck Rogers backpack and it works on very little force (small thrusters) to move the guys around where ever they want to point themselves.  It's worn for backup only still. Maybe someday there will be freeflight in space though. Some fireworks bring their own oxygen with them and would "ignite" in space.  Any action (i.e. thrusters or fireworks) causes an opposite reaction (freeflight in space).

Comment: Did you, perhaps, mean to include a link or image? It doesn't seem to have made it.